# Installed Ubuntu on Surface Book. No inputs

Tags: windows, microsoft, surface

I installed Ubuntu on my Surface Book this week, wiping Windows. During installation I noticed that the keyboard and mouse weren't working, so I used USB to install, deciding I'd fix the inputs later if they still didn't work. I genuinely thought I'd get my head around this, but I still haven't. Is there a way to repair the input drivers so they work like normal again, or am I going to have to re-install Windows 10? I just don't know quite where to look for the drivers, or at least in a format that would make them usable on Ubuntu.

Comment: You might find some useful info on [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/3qcqha/ubuntu_on_surface_book/)

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't work straight out of the box on a surface book. You need to use an external keyboard after installation to get the dock to work. I followed [these instructions](https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.reddit.com/r/SurfaceLinux/comments/4l8iv1/surface_book_1604_install_step_by_step/) and Ubuntu 16.04 works on my surface book. In summary:

- Create a partition for Ubuntu in Windows
- Download Ubuntu 16.04 ISO image, and set up Live USB install using rufus: https://rufus.akeo.ie/
- Enter UEFI settings by shutting down surface, press and hold volume up button on surface, and at the same time press and release power button
- In UEFI menu disable 'Secure Boot'
- Go to Boot configuration and either: Swipe left on 'USB Storage' OR configure boot order so that USB Storage is on top, then restart

Install Ubuntu, then in a terminal, run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/tigerite/kernel/ubuntu trusty main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tigerite-kernel-trusty.list
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 984AE706D31B333A && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-surface
```

And reboot